# Как найти нужный TextView внутри элемента списка ? Android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. У меня возникла задача. В приложении есть список ListView , где каждый элемент списка представлен при помощи item_list.xml . Внутри item_list есть кнопка. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, я мог брать текст из TextView, который находится внутри того же элемента списка, что и кнопка?  Ниже прикрепил код из адаптера.

item_list.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,VectorDrawableCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#232323"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categoryDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/categoryName"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"

        android:text="@string/more"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryVariant"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"
        app:iconTint="@color/colorPrimaryVariant"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.538"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

CategoriesAdapter.java

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
        categoryName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        categoryDescription = convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryDescription);
        categoryName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCategoryName());
        categoryDescription.setText(arrayList.get(position).getCategoryDescription());

        categoryImg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.get().load(arrayList.get(position).getUrl()).resize(185, 185).placeholder(R.drawable.common_full_open_on_phone).into(categoryImg);

        more = convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        
        more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TAGW", String.valueOf(position));
                TextView s = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categoryName);

                Log.d("TAGS", s.getText().toString());
                // На этом моменте выдает NullPointerException 
                // Отслеживание нажатия на кнопку внутри элемента списка
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я случайно пофиксил проблему добавив следующий код в адаптер в метод getView. Определил новый экземпляр класса View finalConvertView;

```
View finalConvertView = convertView; // определил экземпляр класса View
        more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(position));
                TextView s = (TextView) finalConvertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName); 
                // обращение к нужному TextView

                Log.d("TAGS", s.getText().toString());
                // Отслеживание нажатия на кнопку внутри элемента списка
            }
        });
```